# How can I upload host a image in imgbb (a third party hosting provider) from Express.js server?

Tags: reactjs

I am a new junior React.js developer. I need to use exporess.js as well for REST APIs. Recently, I have been required to host some images for an assignment. I am hosting it in MongoDB as base64. But my MongoDB storage will fill soon. So, how can I host the photos in Imgbb from Express.js Server through their API? As I know, they allow us to host a complete picture under 32 Mb file size. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you read their documentation ? https://api.imgbb.com/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.